Op amp GBW compensation when used in MFB filter
I've been reading through this app note by TI where its proposed that when using a MFB filter a compensation resistor can be added to overcome limitations of lower GBW op amps. I've been working through the derivation but am getting hung up.  The app note first provides the TF for the low pass MFB filter:
$$F(s) = \frac{-a_2}{s^2(RC)^2 \times a_1a_2a_3 + sRC \times a_1a_2a_3\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}\right)+1}$$
and then defines the TF for a real op amp as:
$$A(s)=\frac{\text{GBW}}{s}$$
The real op amp TF is introduced into the original TF:
$$F(s) = \frac{-a_2}{b_3s^3+b_2s^2+b_1s+b_0}$$
where the coefficients are defined:
$$b_0 = 1$$
$$b_1 = \frac{a_2}{\text{GBW}} + \frac{1}{\text{GBW}}+CRa_1a_3 +CRa_2a_3+CRa_1a_2a_3$$
$$b_2 = \frac{CRa_2}{\text{GBW}} + \frac{CRa_1a_3}{\text{GBW}}+\frac{CRa_1a_2a_3}{\text{GBW}}+\frac{CRa_2a_3}{\text{GBW}}+C^2R^2a_1a_2a_3$$
$$b_3 = \frac{C^2R^2a_1a_2a_3}{\text{GBW}}$$
I've been trying to work through this step of the derivation but am seeing how the result is derived.  Can I treat the new transfer function as original TF cascaded with op amp TF such that the new TF = F(s)A(s)?  When trying to approach the derivation in this manner I start with
$$F(s) = \frac{-\text{GBW}a_2}{s^3(RC)^2a_1a_2a_3+s^2RCa_1a_2a_3\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}\right)+1}$$
I can divide through by GBW to keep the equation in the form as defined by the app note and b3 coefficient will match but none of the others match.  If this is the right first step I need to keep b0 = 1 but I'm not sure how to do that while dividing through by GBW.

If you are really interested in compensating for the influence of non-ideal components on the filter function, then I would like to recommend TWO DIFFERENT METHODS.
This involves using one of the well-known circuit simulation programs (with a realistic opamp model).
FIRST METHOD
This method compensates for both (numerically known) deviations of the passive components from the calculated (ideal) values as well as non-ideal opamp characteristics (finite GBW, finite input and output impedances).
This method makes use of the substitution theorem of network theory.
As a result, one of the calculated passive components is replaced by a suitable series or parallel resistor-capacitor combination
Reference:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301198883_On_Computer-Aided_Optimization_of_RC-Active_Filter_Designs
SECOND METHOD
Here are the basic steps for compensating transfer function errors
caused by parasitics and other non-idealities of active and passive devices.
1.) Create two circuits (PSpice: Schematic entry )in one single input file for simulation:
(a) with ideal components, (b) with real components and parasitics.
2.) Drive both circuits (real and ideal) with a common ac input  signal (see remark).
3.) Connect both opamp outputs to the differential input nodes of a ideal high-gain amplifier block E_value (with differential input and output).
4.) Select one suitable passive part X (resistor,capacitor) from the real circuit and replace this part by connecting the differential output of the E-block to the two open nodes (X and Y, see diagram).
5) Perform an ac analysis of the whole system in the vicinity of the pole frequency fp (see remark).
6.) The negative feedback causes the differential input voltage of E to be nearly zero (that means:Both output signals of the circuits are nearly equal).
7.) For any frequency to be selected you can use some special formulas to calculate the values of a new complex impedance (R-C seriesor R-C parallel) which should be used to replace the removed passive part X.
8.) Result: At the selected frequency (recommended: pole frequency fp) , both circuit outputs (real and ideal) now are equal. Up to a certain degree, this corrects the whole transfer function.

Remark:
This compensation method was used with good results to correct the
transfer function of active filters for relatively high pole frequencies (non-idealities of the opamp and aditional capacitive parasitics).
For this purpose, the method can be applied to both input-output transfer functions of the closed-loop filter functions.
However, it is strongly recommended to apply the optimization procedure to the LOOP GAIN functions (instead of the closed-loop filter function). In this case, the source ue (see diagram) is to be replaced by the test voltage injected into the open loop ("normal" filter input grounded).
As a result, both loop gain functions (real and ideal) could be made identical at the pole frequency fp. More than that, in this case also the desired transfer functions of both filters (real and ideal) are very close to each other (not only at the pole frequency).

Here are the formulas to be used (for defining corresponding macros):
A) Definitions:
ur=R[V(Y)-V(X)] ; ui=IMG[V(Y)-V(X)]  ;
ir=R[i(Vz)] ; ii=IMG[i(Vz)]
B) Correction with Rs-Cs series:
Rs = (ur * ir + ui * ii) / (ir * ir + ii * ii)
Cs = (ir * ir + ii * ii) / [wp * (ur * ii  - ui * ir)]
C) Correction with Rp-Cp parallel:
Rp = (ur * ur + ui * ui) / (ur * ir + ui * ii)
Cp = (ur * ii - ui * ir) / [wp * (ur * ur  + ui * ui)]
EXAMPLE:
Here are the results after applying the above described method for compensationg the influence of non-dealities (tolerances, parasitics, finite GBW) on the transfer function of a multi-feedback lowpass filter (opamp: AD822).
curve 1: Ideal; curve 2: Real; curve 3: compensated.


At a high level what I believe you're proposing is that I use simulation SW to characterize the difference between my op amp of interest and an ideal op amp and then in simulations tune the feedback network with voltage sources so that real op amp matches ideal op amp behavior and based on substitution theorem calculate impedance that the voltage source emulates and use this new impedance in feedback network?  Do you have any example spice files that you could share that I could review to better understand the steps to implement this type of procedure?

@Bolpincal - do you have access to the mentioned document? The method is described and an example is presented. In addition, I could send you a pdf-copy of the article. By the way - there is another method with the same capabilities. In both cases - one point of the real  filter function is shifted to the desired ideal design value - in most cases, this point should be the value at the pole frequency.

I do have the mentioned doc but I don't understand some of the implementation details.  When the sub loop is opened at point A and a 100khz signal is injected, how is the subloop gain measured? I can run an AC analysis but I am not reproducing the same results as the pdf.
The tuner block is just a behavioral voltage source placed between output and R5? Are A_T and phi_T just the constants that were measured in the subloop sim and s just the static frequency fp?

My understanding of running these types of sims is pretty basic. I haven't done much more than bode plot simulations and noise analysis when evaluating op amp filters. If there are additional resources that I should read to better understand the simulation process that this paper is proposing please feel free to suggest.

@Bolpincal - are you familiar with the term "loop gain" and how it is found by simulation? Are you familiar with the oscillation condition (unity loop gain) ? Such a knowledge is necessary in order to know whats going on when you try to undestand and to apply the method under discussion.

yes I'm familiar with loop gain and oscillation condition.  So revisiting the first step of the paper, I'm setting up an ideal op amp circuit that matches that shown in fig 3, breaking the loop in the feedback network and injecting a small signal into the R||P network of the inverting node.  I'm running an AC analysis to measure simulated loop gain of the ideal circuit but I see a loop gain of 34 dB and phase of 91 deg instead of the paper's reported values of Al = 1.0244 and phase = 5.5725 deg.

@Bolpincal - did you open the loop at point A (the feedback capacitor still connected to the opamp output)? And did you measure the loop gain at f=fp BETWEEN A and B [V(A)/V(B)] ?

I think I got the expected output of the ideal OA simulation now.  I'm seeing phase of 5.57 deg but loop gain of 0.2 dB instead of 1dB which I imagine is due to difference in tools used.  See attached for initial circuit: https://i.sstatic.net/QsGGAMVn.png
I've added a tuner that can take in a current source as an input but in LTspice I don't see way to add a current source that is in the s domain without making it a voltage controlled current source. https://i.sstatic.net/gR02PTIz.png.  I'll continue to look at how I might be able to do this in LTspice.  Do I seem to be on the right path?

@Bolpincal - please note that my result (1.0244) is identical to your result (0.2 dB). But I must admit that I am not very familiar with LTSpice as I always use PSpice only.

I was able to get access to PSpice by TI.  I've reproduced the initial results in PSpice and am working on adding the tuning network.  I've made an initial attempt at adding the tuning block by connecting a Glaplace block to a Hlaplace block but get errors for floating nodes.
https://i.sstatic.net/gYCKbl6I.png
Even if it were to simulate, Iload would be a function of V out of tuner rather than current.  Idk how to define in terms of current yet.  I can spend time looking through user manuals but are these the functional blocks I should be learning about to implement this?

@Bolpincal - here some information about the controlled sources. The TUNER block (E) is inserted between nodes A and B with both negative input and output terminals grounded. The current source (G) is necessary only when you want to compensate the (small) opamp output impedance. Both input terminals and one output node (with the arrow) of this block G are also grounded. The controlling function of G is specified as a math expression. It is controlled by the output current of E. The corresponding path, therefore, must have a zero source Vz for using the expression I(Vz) in the G function.

Oh - I forgot to mention that the other output node of G is connected to node A - in parallel to the TUNER block E.

I've gotten the tuning circuit modified as I believe you described: https://i.sstatic.net/gYVz5L1I.png.  I've plotted real and imaginary components going through the input of the tuning block (IR(E1:IN+) and II(E1:IN-) and have used these values to calculate Rp and Cp but I'm seeing values of 4185 ohm and 731 pF respectively.  I continue to have the loop opened between inverting input and tuning input and am injecting voltage into that node which I believe is the correct approach to inject Vz? https://i.sstatic.net/1KZKU193.png.

@Bolpincal - Let me summarize the method (to avoid misunderstandings): (1) Find the IDEAL loop gain in the vicinty of fp (opamp ideal and calculated parts values); (2) Define the TUNER block (inverse loop gain values) and place it between the loop opening nodes; (3) Select a suitable part for modification and replace it by a voltage source Vz=1V; (4)  perform an ac analysis around fp for the REAL circuit (real opamp and real parts and find new values for R and C (for replacement of Vz); (5) Remove the TUNER, close the loop and confirm (ac analysis) that the circuit is optimized.

I thought that's what I had done?  I used an ideal op amp and opened the subloop to find the ideal subloop phase and gain, used that inverse gain and phase to define the tuner block with the elaplace and glaplace functions and placed said tuner block between points A and B of the figure.  I removed resistor R5 and injected a voltage source Vz between points B and C, ran an AC sweep and measured real and imaginary components of Iz at fp (100khz) and used these values to calculate Rp and Cp.

As previously mentioned, to inject Vz I am still breaking the loop between op amp inverting input and point B of fig 3 and injecting Vz.  I guess I'd be effectively treating nodes B and C as the same node which may be incorrect?  When doing a final AC sweep to verify I would connect an AC source at input of circuit and would plot output over frequency to verify shape of filter.  To implement substitution should I be providing AC source at input and just substituting R5 with a sine wave source at 100khz? If I try this I still get incorrect values.  https://i.sstatic.net/fzoYS5X6.png

@Bolpical - From your drawing I see that the output of the TUNER  is connected to the opamp output ? Or did I misinterpret the drawing?

yes, that is correct.  The TUNER input is connected to Vz and TUNER output is connected to opamp output which should be node A in fig 3, correct?

@Bolpincal - It is the purpose of the TUNER to insert a certain gain constant and a certain phase into the loop in order to give the selected feedback loop a loop gain unity at one single frequency. This is the basis of the method. Where did you get the idea of connecting the output of one unit with the output of another?

Taking step back.  TUNER is defined with gain and phase from ideal OA sim. This TUNER is going to receive an input and because TF is defined by subloop gain and phase, output of tuner with real OA will be what it would have been in previous ideal OA case.  I replace R5 with Vz and current/voltage of Vz gives me impedance.  So I need to have tuner input connected to OA output.  Do I also need to inject a voltage into input of tuner to guarantee that output of tuner is same subloop gain as was previously simulated with ideal OA? something like this:
https://i.sstatic.net/GhRy2OQE.png

Bolpincal - You wrote: "...tuner input conncted to OA output". Yes, that is correct. But in the diagram both outputs were connected to each other!. More than that - try to understand the principle of the method. In your last drawing I see loop gain configuration with the Blocks E and G connected. In addition there are TWO ac sources effective. This is wrong. You need to perform loop gan simulations only once - with ideal OA. After inserting E the closed loop must be simulated with only one ac source Vz. (I recommed - as a 1st step -  to forget about the G block; it has only minor influence !)

@Bolpincal - I try to summarize with words: First ac simulation for finding the IDEAL loop gain (magnitude and phase) at the filters pole frequency fp. These values are used to define a TUNER block which allows the loop gain to be unity at f=fp. Next ac simulation: Closed-loop with E inserted into the loop and ac stimulus Vz=1v (replacement of a suitable part). Then, calculation of new R and C values (based on the substitution theorem), which will replace Vz. End of the procedure.

thank you for the explanation.  I understand now.

@Bolpincal - it seems that you are intersted in such optimization procedures. Therefore, I have edited my contribution with a second method for correcting filter functions (seems to be simpler than the 1st method)
